# MapView breaks TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a 1x2 TableLayout with MapView in one of the cells.

I'm using the following layout template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:stretchColumns="0,1"
          android:padding="5dp">

    <TableRow>
        <Button android:text="123" />

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
            android:apiKey="054E5p80TEOX6y_rf3lKv4rZBPOWv1N2FnYGkjw"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

As a result i've got a table stretched to full width and full height with a little button at the left and a huge map at the right. But i expecting what both button and map will be 50% width. And if i put another button instead of map it works just fine - buttons are drawn with same the width.

Is it a MapView issue or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a 1x2 TableLayout with MapView in one of the cells.

Why not use a `LinearLayout`? A `TableLayout` only makes sense with at least two rows and two columns.

> But i expecting what both button and map will be 50% width.

Why not use a `LinearLayout`? Set both widgets' `android:layout_width="0px"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`.